# Bash script can be called from command line, but not from Python script

Tags: python, linux

I have the following script `utils/pdf2image.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
pdftoppm -png $1 $2
```

and the following snippet of Python code:

```
script_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'utils', 'pdf2image.sh') + ' ' + invoice_path + ' ' + invoice_path[:-4]
subprocess.call(script_path, shell=True)
```

When I call the script in command line, it works, but when I call it from Python, it doesn't, saying that `pdftoppm` doesn't work. I checked and `poppler-utils` is installed. I suspect that `pdftoppm` can't be seen from Python environment. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you post the complete error?

Comment: First problem: you need to quote `$1` and `$2` in your script. Second problem: you don't need to use the shell to execute this command. `subprocess.call(os.path.join('utils', 'pdf2image.sh'), invoice_path, invoice_path[:-4])` should work (or at least provide a better starting point for debugging).

Comment: @chepner, isn't that missing a list constructor? I'd expect it to be `subprocess.call([os.path.join('utils', 'pdf2image.sh'), invoice_path, invoice_path[:-4]])`

Comment: @z3u5, ...using `shell=True` introduces security bugs -- what happens if someone runs your script against a PDF with `$(rm -rf ~)` in its name? (And you can't fix those bugs just by adding constant quotes, because a filename can _also_ contain quotes that reverse the ones you add during string construction).

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to pack the arguments in a list.

Comment: @z3u5, ...the other thing is that getting rid of the `shell=True` will give you better error messages; Python itself will be executing your script, which means Python knows why the execution fails and can create a more appropriate exception object, instead of Python-starting-a-shell-that-executes-the-script (which means Python can tell _that_ the shell it started is reporting an exit status indicative of failure, but often can't tell why).

Comment: Thank you guys. I read your comments and fixed it.

Comment: I used this approached because I couldn't get pdf2image to work. The problem I suspect is that pdftoppm from pdf2image uses the wrong path. Any idea how I could also fix this and stop using pdftoppm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user's `PATH` and the script's `PATH` aren't necessarily the same, so it seems that the BASH script being called from inside the Python script doesn't know where `pdftoppm` is.

You have two options:

1. Calling the full path to `pdftoppm` inside the BASH script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/pdftoppm -png $1 $2
```

2. Calling `pdftoppm` directly from the Python script:

```py
script_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'utils', 'pdf2image.sh') + ' ' + invoice_path + ' ' + invoice_path[:-4]
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/pdftoppm', '-png', invoice_path, invoice_path[:-4]])
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. What steps should I take to make it work without the full path? To understand better, I used this approached because I couldn't get pdf2image to work. The problem I suspect is that pdftoppm from pdf2image uses the wrong path.

Comment: You can add the path to your shell script with `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/bin` or add it to your python script with `import sys; sys.path.append('/usr/bin')`

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm understanding on your problem, the Python code is unable to locate the `pdftoppm` . This can happen if that binary is not present in the `$PATH`.

I would recommend to make use of the absolute path to the `pdftoppm` if that's the case in that shell script and then try invoking the shell script from Python.

Though as the comments to your question have pointed out already that the script's piece of work can be done by subprocess itself, you should give that a shot as well :)

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Any idea how to make pdftoppm when called from Python to the path of pdftoppm outseide Pyhton?